# Not serving a CSS to IE7 & IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Is there an easy way to serve a whole stylesheet to every modern Browser but IE7 and IE8? Some kind of inverted conditional comments?

Comment: Are server-side solutions allowed?

Comment: @mellamokb: No. (no need for them here and they can be unreliable)

Comment: @thirtydot: Time to brush up on my HTML conditional comments :)

Comment: Server-side would be the last resort. I can't figure out how to solve it with conditional comments, since other Browsers ignore them.

Comment: I still think it would be easier to re-order your CSS files.  Distribute one CSS to all browsers, and ONLY distribute a "corrections" CSS to the IE browsers you wish to fix.  It requires more up-front cost (re-tooling the CSS files), but will likely save you headaches later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work per [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if !((IE 7)|(IE 8))]><!--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /><!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Does the `!` operator serve to negate ***both*** the `(IE 7)` *and* `(IE 8)` sub-expressions?

Comment: It translates as NOT (IE 7 OR IE 8).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that, I just wasn't sure that it would serve to apply the `NOT` to *both* the terms in the sub-expression; hence my question. Also the +1 is mine, since this is the best standards compatible approach to the problem.

Comment: It does because of the parenthesis around the entire or statement. `!(IE 7) & !(IE 8)` would also work.

Comment: I think you need to close the comment for other browsers after the condition. So it should be `<!--[if !((IE 7)|(IE 8))><!-->…<!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: The initial one doesn't work and the changed Thing by Richard M will load the CSS in any browser.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the closing square bracket. I can't edit my comment now, so I've just edited Andrews's answer. Hope this is OK Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about web coding... but [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) looks like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN docs are very useful here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that you can use "!" to denote "not". So you could use something like this:

```
<!-- [if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)]>
<link href="modern.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Pretty straight forward.

**Updated**
Since IE's quirky conditionals don't get respected in other browsers. You could easily add jQuery to the page and do something like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<!-- add jquery first for browser sniffing -->
<script>
  // if broswer is IE and less than version 9 write out the nice CSS
  if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 9){
    document.write("<link href='modern.css'/>");
  }
</script>
```

jQuery docs on browser sniffing: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: stupid question but can you use javascript or do you support JS disabled browsers?

Comment: Be careful when using browser sniffing, straight from the jQuery docs: "We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser will be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery."

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this site](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

If you are simply trying to exclude browsers older than IE9, it is simpler to use

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <link ...
<![end if]-->
```

Otherwise, you will need to use other operators to fit a specific subset, as others have already provided.

Comment: that wouldn't serve the file to non-IE browsers, which is what he's trying to do.

Comment: but it still won't be loaded in any other browser, thats not IE

Comment: Why not reverse the conditions, serve a CSS file to all browsers, and use the conditional `[if lt IE 9]` to override those definitions that need overwritten?  It may be more complex to rewrite everything this way, but would probably make better sense going forward.